# AS2 code to AS3 code help converting!

Tags: actionscript-3

Help!!! This as2 code has given me a mind numbing headache. Can someone help me convert it to AS3. Here is the code:

```
import flash.filters.GlowFilter;

//Settings
var maxDist:Number = 400;
var accuracy:Number = 1;

//other vars (do not edit)
var dx:Number;
var dy:Number;
var startX:Number;
var startY:Number;
var endX:Number;
var endY:Number;
var realDist:Number;
var rad:Number = Math.PI/180;
var rad2:Number = 180/Math.PI;
map_mc.createEmptyMovieClip("laser_mc", map_mc.getNextHighestDepth());

//Glow Filter 
var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();
glow.color = 0xFF0000;
glow.alpha = 1;
glow.blurX = 7;
glow.blurY = 7;
glow.quality = 2;
map_mc.laser_mc.filters = new Array(glow);

/**
*
* Mouse Controls
*
*/
//create an object that we'll listen to
mouseListener = new Object();

//on Click, fire the weapon
mouseListener.onMouseDown = function() {
    fireWeapon();
}
//on release, stop weapon firing
mouseListener.onMouseUp = function() {
    stopWeapon();
}
//on mouse move, rotate the player
mouseListener.onMouseMove = function() {
    rotatePlayer();
}
//add listener
Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);


/**
*
* Laser Weapon
*
*/
//fire weapon function - creates an onEnterFrame function to repeat updateLaser() over and over
function fireWeapon():Void 
{
    _root.onEnterFrame = function ():Void {
        updateLaser();
    }
}

//stop weapon function - deletes onEnterFrame and clears laser movieclip
function stopWeapon():Void 
{   
    delete _root.onEnterFrame;
    map_mc.laser_mc/**/.clear();
}

//Update Laser Function
function updateLaser() :Void
{       
    //run a loop 
    for (realDist=0; realDist<maxDist; realDist += accuracy) 
    {       
        //get end X&Y
        endX = map_mc.player_mc._x + Math.cos(map_mc.player_mc._rotation * rad) * realDist;
        endY = map_mc.player_mc._y + Math.sin(map_mc.player_mc._rotation * rad) * realDist;

        //calculate hit test
        if (map_mc.walls_mc.hitTest(endX, endY, true)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    //calculate the tip of the barrel (start X & Y)
    startX = map_mc.player_mc._x + 15 * Math.cos(map_mc.player_mc._rotation * rad);
    startY = map_mc.player_mc._y + 15 * Math.sin(map_mc.player_mc._rotation * rad);

    // Clear it before we draw, so the line doesnt stay there
    map_mc.laser_mc.clear();

    //draw laser
    map_mc.laser_mc.lineStyle(2, 0xFF0000, 75);
    map_mc.laser_mc.moveTo(startX, startY);
    map_mc.laser_mc.lineTo(endX, endY);
}

//rorate player towards mouse function
function rotatePlayer():Void
{
    //get distance between mouse and player
    dx = map_mc._xmouse-map_mc.player_mc._x;
    dy = map_mc._ymouse-map_mc.player_mc._y;

    //calculate rotation of player
    map_mc.player_mc._rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx)*rad2;
}
```

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the bulk of it
You shouldn't get compile errors now
Plus I cleaned it up
You will also have to fix your rotation point of player_mc

```
import flash.filters.GlowFilter;

//Settings
var maxDist:Number = 400;
var accuracy:Number = 1;

//other vars (do not edit)
var dx:Number;
var dy:Number;
var startX:Number;
var startY:Number;
var endX:Number;
var endY:Number;
var realDist:Number;
var rad:Number = Math.PI/180;
var rad2:Number = 180/Math.PI;

var laser_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip()
map_mc.addChild(laser_mc)

//Glow Filter 
var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();
glow.color = 0xFF0000;
glow.alpha = 1;
glow.blurX = 7;
glow.blurY = 7;
glow.quality = 2;
laser_mc.filters = new Array(glow);

/**
*
* Mouse Controls
*
*/
stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fire);
//on Click, fire the weapon
function fire( e:Event ):void {
    stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME , updateLaser)
}

stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopFire);
//on release, stop weapon firing
function stopFire( e:Event ):void {
    laser_mc.graphics.clear();
    stage.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME , updateLaser)
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoved)
//on mouse move, rotate the player
function mouseMoved( e:Event ):void {
    //get distance between mouse and player
    dx = map_mc.mouseX-map_mc.player_mc.x;
    dy = map_mc.mouseY-map_mc.player_mc.y;

    //calculate rotation of player
    map_mc.player_mc.rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx)*rad2;
}

//Update Laser Function
function updateLaser( e:Event ):void {
    //run a loop 
    for (realDist=0; realDist<maxDist; realDist += accuracy){       
        //get end X&Y
        endX = map_mc.player_mc.x + Math.cos(map_mc.player_mc.rotation * rad) * realDist;
        endY = map_mc.player_mc.y + Math.sin(map_mc.player_mc.rotation * rad) * realDist;

        //calculate hit test
        if (map_mc.walls_mc.hitTestPoint(endX,endY)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    //calculate the tip of the barrel (start X & Y)
    startX = map_mc.player_mc.x + 15 * Math.cos(map_mc.player_mc.rotation * rad);
    startY = map_mc.player_mc.y + 15 * Math.sin(map_mc.player_mc.rotation * rad);

    //draw laser
    laser_mc.graphics.clear();
    laser_mc.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xFF0000);
    laser_mc.graphics.moveTo(startX, startY);
    laser_mc.graphics.lineTo(endX, endY);
}
```

Comment: I would probably change the event handlers' names from `fire()`, `stopFire()`, `mouseMoved()`, `updateLaser()` to `onStageMouseUp()`, `onStageMouseDown()`, `onStageMouseMove()`, `onStageEnterFrame()` respectively. Also `map_mc.player_mc` will probably throw an error along the lines of "Error: Access of possibly undefined property player_mc through a reference with static type flash.display:MovieClip", the reason being that your have to use the `map_mc` display object's `getChildByName()` method to access the `player_mc` display object(e.g. `map_mc.getChildByName("player_mc")`).

Comment: Yeah there are a bunch of changes I would make also. I only spent 10 mintues converting it. I figured he could finish it as he learns AS3

Comment: Oh yeah and map_mc.player_mc is perfectly fine to use. can also just reference it with player_mc

Comment: i keep getting this output error TypeError: Error #1006: hitTest is not a function.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/updateLaser()

Comment: change hitTest to hitTestObject

Comment: @Thor625 try tracing `map_mc.player_mc` and `map_mc.laser_mc`. Add the traces after the 18th line(`map_mc.addChild(laser_mc)`).

Comment: @Taurayi ok you do have a point however trace(map_mc.player_mc) does show the object it seems adding laser_mc to map_mc and giving it a name laser_mc still doesn't act the same. So what am I missing. A movieClip added at author time works but a movieClip added at run time doesn't. All I do is flex apps anymore and its been years since I have played with the flash ide but why am I getting 2 different results depending on how/when the movieCLip was created

Comment: @Thor625 Answer updated and completed your code conversion don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: the only thing is that i cant do anything with wall unless it is a square block....

Comment: Pretty much. You asked for a conversion not a redesign. Post another question on that topic.